# ICollectionView DataGrid is staying updated even after cancelling edit window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I have a problem and maybe someone had this situation in his C#/WPF/MVVM app.

I have the DataGrid populated by data from database (using Prism.MVVM), also I am using ICollectionView to can filter this DataGrid in realtime.

For editing I have new dialog window with textboxes etc. binded to SelectedItem. Everything is working fine except one thing. When I edit some values in (lets called it) "Edit Mode", data is updated real time in DataGrid and this is okay (update to database is after I press "Save" button), but even if I press Cancel button, values stayed updated in DataGrid.

Database is not getting updated as it supposed, but datagrid does. Using .Refresh() method of ICollectionView do nothing, only way to get it back to normal is restarting an app.

XAML for DataGrid in View (simplified for readability):

```
                    <DataGrid ColumnWidth="Auto" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsCollectionView}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"
                                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding EditCommand}"/>
                    </DataGrid.InputBindings>

                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sygnatura" Binding="{Binding Signature}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nazwa" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Stan" Binding="{Binding InStock}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterValues}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cena zakupu" Binding="{Binding PurchasePrice, StringFormat=N2}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterValues}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cena SRP" Binding="{Binding SellPrice, StringFormat=N2}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterValues}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cena FRN" Binding="{Binding FranPrice, StringFormat=N2}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterValues}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rodzaj produktu" Binding="{Binding ProductType.Name}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterValues}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Manager" Binding="{Binding Seller.Symbol}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterValues}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Opakowanie" Binding="{Binding Package.Symbol}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterValues}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

ViewModel (For window with DataGrid):

```
public class ProductListViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ICollectionView ProductsCollectionView { get; }
    private ProductService _service;

    private ObservableCollection<Product> _data;
    public ObservableCollection<Product> Data
    {
        get => _data;
        set => SetProperty(ref _data, value);
    }

    private Product _selectedItem;
    public Product SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set => SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);
    }

    private string _filterBar = string.Empty;
    public string FilterBar
    {
        get { return _filterBar; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _filterBar, value);
            ProductsCollectionView.Refresh();
        }
    }

    public ProductListViewModel()
    {
        _service = new ProductService();
        Load();

        ProductsCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Data);
        ProductsCollectionView.Filter = FilterProducts;

        LoadCommands(); // <- This contains: EditCommand = new DelegateCommand(Edit);
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        Data = new ObservableCollection<Product>(_service.GetAllProducts());
    }

    private void Edit()
    {
        var dialog = new ProductView(SelectedItem);

        dialog.ShowDialog();

        if (dialog.DialogResult == true)
        {
            _service.UpdateProductData(SelectedItem);
            _service.SaveChanges();
            ProductsCollectionView.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

ProductView (Example binding)

```
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,13,0" Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Text="Sygnatura" Style="{StaticResource StackPanelTextBox}"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Data.Signature}"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

ProductViewModel

```
public class ProductViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private Product _data;
    public Product Data
    {
        get => _data;
        set => SetProperty(ref _data, value);

    }

    public ICommand Save { get; set; }
    public ICommand Cancel { get; set; }

    public ProductViewModel(Product data)
    {

        EditMode();
        LoadSellers();
        LoadProductTypes();
        LoadPackages();

        Data = data;

        Save = new DelegateCommand(() => SaveAction?.Invoke()); // Sets dialog.DialogResoult == true
        Cancel = new DelegateCommand(() => CancelAction?.Invoke());  // Sets dialog.DialogResoult == false

    }
}
```

I will be glad for help

Comment: I am guessing (could be wrong) but, can you try with INotifyPropertyChanged interface and check if your SelectedItem is getting updated or not. Other possible guess is since the object is updated while you press in Edit mode, the same values are persisted in the Data-Grid even if you have cancelled it, because it has overridden the data in old object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented by Prism.MVVM. You right about probability overriding data I've figured this out too. Now I would like to disable this realtime updating and update it only when I press Save button OR after pressing "Cancel" get DataGrid (or only this row of data) to previous state without some hard walkaround coding or loading database again.

Comment: There is an updatesourcetrigger=Explicit when you decide when values are updated [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-data-updatesourcetrigger-explicit) but you are using prism, not sure how it handles these.

Comment: In that case I would suggest bind a different object to the pop-up window. Don't modify the original object (SelectedItem in your case). So when user clicks on Save you update back the SelectedItem. This is the easiest solution I feel.

Comment: If you make a better design of your WPF application, each view has its own ViewModel. In that case you don't face the problem of what you are facing it today.

Comment: Well, easy part: Clone your product data, work on the clone and after successful save to database update assign that values to the original one